# Want to read a file to a TStringList

Tags: delphi, file-io, tstringlist

Yes I want to read a simple a logfile into a TStringList and that is easy done with LoadFromFile. But the problem is that the file can be already opened by another program at the same time so an exception may appear. I have tried to use:

```
FileMode := fmShareCompat;
```

But it won't work.

I have also tried to use:

```
fFilePath := fPathList[PathIndex] + '\' + FileData.Name;
AssignFile(vFile, fFilePath);
Reset(vFile, 1);  // Recordsize = 1

SetLength(vFileString, FileData.Size);
BlockRead(vFile, vFileString, FileData.Size);   
vCurrentFile.Text := vFileString;
```

It raise an EInOutError with message I/O error 998.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try *LoadFromStream* and do something like:

```
fileStream := TFileStream.Create(aFileName, fmShareDenyNone);
myTStringList.LoadFromStream(fileStream);
fileStream.Free();
```

Comment: Do not call Destroy directly in an application. Instead, call Free, which checks that the TFileStream reference is not nil and only then calls Destroy.

Comment: Correction: Destroy is quite acceptable in the above example. `MyObject.Free` is equivalent to `if MyObject <> nil then MyObject.Destroy`. The reason you use `Free` is to provide a check whether the reference has been assigned. In the above example you can safely guarantee that by reaching line 3 that `fileStream` references an object that was correctly created. What is missing however (an much more of an issue) is the `try..finally` statement. Also, depending on the scope of the `fileStream` variable, it may be advisable to clear it: `finally fileStream.Destroy; fileStream := nil; end;`

Comment: before a discussion about Free or Destroy starts you may want to read this: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer

Comment: I was always somehow confused why there are two methods available, and honestly I almost in every case use Destroy over Free. This is because it will throw an exception in cases I have not assigned the object and so bugs are faster detected.

Comment: I couldn't find the discussion on allen bauer's blog.  For some reason I thought it was bad to invoke Destroy too. (inzKulozik's comment).  I didn't know it was safe to invoke directly.

Answer (score 4):

fmShareCompat should probably be marked as deprecated.  You want **fmShareDenyNone** ([as Drejc said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445871/want-to-read-a-file-to-a-tstringlist#445877))

fmShareCompat  comes from 16 DOS days I believe.  On Windows, it is treated the same as fmShareExclusive.  When Linux was supported it was treated the same as fmShareDenyNone.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try..except and try..finally are good friends at these times. Encapsulate your file reading code in these types of blocks and tell the user about the problem that arises.

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to search many log-files in a directory. If I have a try except for every file load maybe it slow down the execution. It is already rather slow...

/Roland

Comment: You actually want a try / finally for every file.  Unless you are reading a lot of really small files I don't see it impacting performance significantly.  If it does, then you may want to consider a different mechanism all together.

Comment: @Niklas: NO! NO! NO! and NO again!  Do not abuse try..except! Hiding errors with try..except leads to a huge amount of insidious bugs in the long run.

Comment: @Craig Young: Did you miss the part of my answer that says "...and tell the user about the problem that arises"? That is not hiding errors, that is handling them gracefully in my book.